# Question about the phrase "shines harsh light"

Tags: meaning, headlinese

In the sentence:

> Shutdown shines harsh light on rift in Republican Party

What do they mean?

p.s. "shutdown" here about government shutdown in the US.

Comment: Who are "they"? Where did you get this?

Comment: The authors. I've found it on [washingtonpost](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/shutdown-shines-spotlight-on-rift-in-republican-party/2013/10/07/2d4c90e6-2f9b-11e3-bbed-a8a60c601153_story.html?hpid=z1). And it has different headline on main page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, this is a headline, so it leaves out as much as it can get away with to save space and allow the letters to be printed in a larger font. It represents

> The shutdown shines a harsh light on a rift in the Republican Party.

You indicate that you understand what is meant by *shutdown*.

To *shine a light* on something is to make it more visible or evident. *Harsh light* is a figure of speech from painting and photography: lighting is described as *harsh* when it exposes and draws attention to unpleasant features of the subject instead of blurring and "softening" these features.

A *rift* is a tear or split in something. Here it is employed figuratively to designate a fundamental division in opinion among members of the party.

So:

> The shutdown exposes a distressing division in opinion among Republicans [which the party would rather went unnoticed].

Comment: It's also worth noting that over recent decades, [in the harsh light of day](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+harsh+light+of+day&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) has become an increasingly common "cliche" that usually means *when considered more carefully later on*. I know that in reality the origins lie in painting/photography, but in practice for me personally, I tend to see it as an allusion to having stayed up *late at night* [probably *drinking alcohol*], and having ideas which seemed good at the time, but don't pass muster next day when sober.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as much I can read from that line without further context, I assume the following:

- There's a rift (or disagreement) in the Republican Party
- That rift is brought to attention by a "harsh light"
- That harsh light is emitted by the shutdown

> The shutdown is the reason why attention concentrates on the disagreement in the Republican Party